# React how to update array useState on button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have seen a hundred videos and read about this, and it still doesn't make sense to me. I'm trying to update an array on a button click but when I log out the items array, it's one behind, meaning it's not reactive and gets added on the next paint. Also, I wrapped my Employee component inside a div only to be able to add an 'onClick' to it. Ideally, I'd like the onClick to be on the Employee component itself, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

```
import React, {ReactElement, useState } from "react";
import {TextContainer, Text } from "react-md";
import model from '../Models'
import Employee from './Employee/Employee'
import styles from '../home.module.scss'


export default function Home(): ReactElement {

    const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<any>>([]);


    const addItem = (val:any) => {
        setItems([...items, val ])
        console.log('items :', items)
    }



    return (
          <div className='center'>
          <TextContainer className='center'>
              <Text type='headline-4' style={{color: 'white'}}>Employee List</Text>
          </TextContainer>

          <section className={styles.emp_list}>
              {model.map((props, index) =><div key={index} onClick={() => addItem(props.name)}><Employee key={index} name={props.name} role={props.role} markets={props.markets} image={props.image}/></div>)}
          </section>
          </div>
)}
```

And my Employee component:

```
import React from "react";
import {MediaContainer} from "@react-md/media";
import styles from './employee.module.scss'
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader} from "react-md";


function Employee(props: any) {


   return (
        <Card className={styles.emp_card}>
            <CardHeader>
                <div className={styles.emp_text}>
                    <p key={props.name}>Name:&nbsp; {props.name}</p>
                    <p key={props.role}>Title:&nbsp; {props.role}</p>
                    <p key={props.markets}>Markets:&nbsp; {props.markets[0]} {props.markets[1] && <span>and {props.markets[1]}</span>}</p>
                </div>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
                <MediaContainer>
                    <img key={props.image} src={props.image} alt="employee"/>
                </MediaContainer>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    )
}


export default Employee;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the documentation is clear enough on this, but if you want to setState using the previous state, then you should pass a function to useState. For example:

```
const addItem = (val:any) => {
    setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, val ])
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I was passing a function.  Either way, I tried your way and I still get the problem of having to click twice to get it to see the item I'm updating the array with. This must be related to me wrapping the Employee component in a div and clicking that. It sees the props at this level, but it's just not working right.

Comment: The problem that drove me nuts had nothing to do with the code. It was the console log I had inside of the function that updated the state looked as if it was one behind, it wasn't. That's asynchronous too so console logs are deceiving!! Lesson learned.